# Proper way to create indexes during deployment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating an expressjs api and using mongodb. I have a decent understanding of indexes and I understand that they are expensive to create when there is data in the database.

In MS Sql Server you would create indexes when creating your database tables. My question is do I handle this creation of indexes in a `post` call in my express app or do I achieve this using scripts when deploymening my application?

For example I need Geospatial indexing.

Would index creation be handled in the express app like this?

```
//express post call
let col = db.collection( 'collection' );
col.createIndex( // someIndex );
col.insertOne( //Some document );
```

I am looking for the best method to creating the 'initial' state of my mongodb and specifically creating indexes I will need for certain collections before these collections contain any documents.

Comment: You can create them when the app starts up and before your http server starts listening.

Comment: Cool that would work. I was leaning towards that but I wasn't able to find an example with a best approach for this. If you make your comment an answer I will mark it as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, It may happen, You have a lot of data in your database while deployment and you do not want your Indexing terrible. Here's what MongoDB can Help. You can do indexing in Background which will not prevent all read and write operations to the database while the index builds.A simple Command:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { a: 1 }, { background: true } )
```

Check the Manual For details.

> https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-in-the-background/